# Trigger inputPanel() after rendering previous plot in R markdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am creating an interactive markdown document that looks like this:

````
---
title: "xxxxxxxxxx"
author: "xxxxxxxxxx"
date: "xxxxxxxxxx"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---


```{r, echo=FALSE}
require(shiny)
textInput("abcd", "Enter the abcd", value = "xxxxxxxxx")


  source("file1.r")
source("file2.R")

renderPlot({
segID = input$abcd
segPlot = getSegPlot(segID)
segPlot
})

renderPlot({
segID = input$abcd
geoPlot = getGeoPlot()
geoPlot
})

renderPlot({
segID = input$abcd
wPlot = getWplot()
wPlot
})

inputPanel(
  selectInput("selectedRegion", label = "Select Region", choices = as.list(getWnames()), selected = getWnames()[1])
  )

```
````

When I run this, the selectInput choices don't get populated. `getWnames()` returns a vector that gets populated in the global scope upon calling the `getWplot()` function (in the previous `renderplot()`). I think that since `getWplot()` takes some time to evaluate, `getWnames()` is populating an empty vector, i.e. it's initial value.

Is my hypothesis correct, and if it is, is there any way I can trigger the `inputPanel()` after the previous `renderPlot()`?

Edit: I realize I am not giving a reproducible example, will create a suitable alternative to my code shortly. Sorry for this, but any help is appreciated!
Edit 2: A second workaround that seems to work- I created the plot objects in the R script itself (file2.R), causing the entire processing to happen upon source. This will need the user to wait a while before anything comes up, but atleast the info comes up right.

Still looking for a more elegant solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, it's hard to know exactly what's happening and try to solve it without a reproducible example.  But it sounds like your hypothesis is correct IMO.

One "solution"/workaround I can think of is to split your Shiny code into a a ui and a server portion, [as described here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_embedded_shiny.html).  Then you can use [renderUI](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderUI.html) with greater control of when to show the data.

Comment: As mush as I wanted to avoid going down that path, it seems this is the only option left! Will give this one a shot.